# Late 50s/early 60s British comic annual: trying to track a "Voyage to centre of the Earth" story

Tags: story-identification, comics

I acquired a hardback comic book annual from a jumble sale/charity shop when I was a kid so the book would have been published late 50s/early 60s ("Eagle" era). Almost certainly British as I don't remember ever seeing American sci-fi hardback story annuals.

The details are as skimpy as they are old. The story featured some vaguely 'human' protagonists (one might have had a big nose?) and was set in caverns, maybe on the moon, maybe underground on Earth. These contained wasp like flying creatures who harassed the heroes. I also remember candy cane type sweets hanging from tree branches, maybe the wasps were defending these or maybe I am confusing two stories. Edit: it was a drawn comic story rather than being text.

This is my "Rosebud" detail, a trivial childhood memory that I would like to identify and perhaps even reread, which would no doubt end in "Oh! Was that it?".

Comment: Can you remember the art style?  Was it more serious?  example:  https://static.wixstatic.com/media/3a61d0_1233a496a5ad4e19baf7ec8e98fbc761.jpg   Or more comical?  example: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/britishcomics/images/5/59/Sids_snake.jpg   Was it black and white? full colour? partial colour? example: https://www.beano.com/wp-content/uploads/legacy/28646_Beano-1964-05-16_14-Billy-Whizz_01.jpg Was the story serious adventure or funny?   (I think it sounds like Dan Dare, but that's just a guess)

Comment: Just possibly the *Doctor Who* comic-book story "The Killer Wasps" (1968). It takes place underground on another planet and has giant wasps. https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Killer_Wasps_(comic_story)

Comment: Good questions, thank you. Excellent suggestion but 1968 would have been too late and it was not Dr Who or any well known character. My memories are B&W (annuals of that period had coloured hard covers and perhaps a few colour pages but were for the most part B&W). The style was less cartoony than Beano but with no attempt at being pseudo realistic. I think it was adventure but clearly cartoony adventure. I doubt it was Eagle but there were scores of that style of Annual published for post austerity Christmases and this would have been one such.

Comment: One reason I am so vague is that we were POOR (3rd world slums poor) and relied on charity handouts for clothes and books. So although I devoured books they appeared pseudo-randomly and so it was not, say, the annual for a comic which I read each week.